# Обработка звукового сигнала

Tags: аудио, matlab, обработка-сигналов

Не могу понять как исправить код по обработке звукового сигнала

сам код:

```
clear all
x=wavread('signal'); 
a=xcorr(x);
z=abs(fft(a,32000));
w=z(1:500);
[f1,f2]=max(w(1:200));
NT=fix((1/f2)*32000)
N=length(x);
kilkNT=fix(N/NT);
NT1=NT-1;
n=NT*(1:kilkNT)-NT1;
for k=1:kilkNT
   b(k,:)=x(n(k):n(k)+NT1);
end;
mx=mean(b);
for k=0:kilkNT-1
    xcentr((1:NT)+k*NT)=x((1:NT)+k*NT)-mean(x); ОШИБКА ТУТ (Error using ==> minus, Matrix dimensions must agree.)
end;
l=1:NT:length(xcentr);
for n=0:NT-1
   kompstac(n+1,1:length(1))=xcentr(1+n);
end;
n=size(kompstac,2);
for k=1:NT
    corkomp(k,:)=corPKVP(compstac(k,:)); ЕЩЕ НЕ УВЕРЕН В ЭТОМ РЯДКЕ (что то с "compstac(k,:)")
end;
surf(corkomp);
shading interp;
axis tight;
grid on;
for k=1:NT
   Bk(k,:)=abs(fft(corkomp(k,:)));
end;
surf(Bk);
shading interp;
axis tight;
grid on;
m=mean(Bk);
plot(m);
axis tight;
grid on;
```

буду очень благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Лень разбираться во всем коде и алгоритме без комментов, первое что приходит в голову - какова размерность `х`?

Насколько помню, mean выдает не среднюю по всей матрице, а только по строке (или столбцу, точно не помню - матлабом за последние два года пользовался раза три) т.е. для `3х4` матрицы `mean(x)` будет размером `1х4`, а для `3х4х5` (в матлабе можно такое создать равно как и еще больше размерностей, только через цикл) и т.п. Чтобы получить скаляр нужно взять

```
mean(mean(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Тут моя ошибка я не посмотрел что загрузил стерео сигнал, а скрипт рассчитан на моно, но все равно спасибо за потраченное время)

```
Но теперь, как я и думал, ошибка тут: 

for k=1:NT

corkomp(k,:)=corPKVP(kompstac(k,:)); 

end;

% исчисления корреляционных компонент сигнала

Ошибка: Undefined function or method 'corPKVP' for input arguments of type 'double'.
Error in ==> corkomp(k,:)=corPKVP(kompstac(k,:));
```

помогите если можете

Если поможет то вот разъяснения к скриптам

```
clear all

x=wavread('signal'); 

% загрузка сигнала

a=xcorr(x);

% исчисления оценки автокорреляционной функции

z=abs(fft(a,32000));

% исчисления оценки спектральной плотности мощности

w=z(1:500);

[f1,f2]=max(w(1:200));

% нахождения максимума в низкочастотные области спектральной плотности мощности сигнала

NT=fix((1/f2)*32000)

% исчисления целого значения периода коррелированности

N=length(x);

kilkNT=fix(N/NT);

NT1=NT-1;

n=NT*(1:kilkNT)-NT1;

for k=1:kilkNT

b(k,:)=x(n(k):n(k)+NT1);

end;

mx=mean(b);

for k=0:kilkNT-kilkNT/2

xcentr((1:NT)+k*NT)=x((1:NT)+k*NT)-mean(x);   

end;

% центрирование сигнала

l=1:NT:length(xcentr);

for n=0:NT-1

kompstac(n+1,1:length(1))=xcentr(1+n);

end;

% формирования стационарных компонент

n=size(kompstac,2);

for k=1:NT

corkomp(k,:)=corPKVP(compstac(k,:));   

end;

% исчисления корреляционных компонент сигнала

surf(corkomp);

shading interp;

axis tight;

grid on;

for k=1:NT

Bk(k,:)=abs(fft(corkomp(k,:)));

end;

% исчисления спектральных компонент сигнала

surf(Bk);

shading interp;

axis tight;

grid on;

m=mean(Bk);

% исчисления усреднения по временным сдвигам

plot(m);

axis tight;

grid on;
```